# Make @lru_cache ignore some of the function arguments

Tags: python, caching, python-decorators, lru, functools

How can I make [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator ignore some of the function arguments with regard to caching key?

For example, I have a function that looks like this:

```
def find_object(db_handle, query):
    # (omitted code)
    return result
```

If I apply `lru_cache` decorator just like that, `db_handle` will be included in the cache key. As a result, if I try to call the function with the same `query`, but different `db_handle`, it will be executed again, which I'd like to avoid. I want `lru_cache` to consider `query` argument only.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

With [cachetools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cachetools/) you can write:

```
from cachetools import cached
from cachetools.keys import hashkey

from random import randint

@cached(cache={}, key=lambda db_handle, query: hashkey(query))
def find_object(db_handle, query):
    print("processing {0}".format(query))
    return query

queries = list(range(5))
queries.extend(range(5))
for q in queries:
    print("result: {0}".format(find_object(randint(0, 1000), q)))
```

You will need to install cachetools (`pip install cachetools`).

The syntax is:

```py
@cached(
    cache={},
    key=lambda <all-function-args>: hashkey(<relevant-args>)
)
```

Here is another example that includes keyword args:

```py
@cached(
    cache={},
    key=lambda a, b, c=1, d=2: hashkey(a, c)
)
def my_func(a, b, c=1, d=2):
    return a + c
```

In the example above note that the lambda function input args match the `my_func` args. You don't have to exactly match the argspec if you don't need to. For example, you can use kwargs to squash out things that aren't needed in the hashkey:

```py
@cached(
    cache={},
    key=lambda a, b, c=1, **kwargs: hashkey(a, c)
)
def my_func(a, b, c=1, d=2, e=3, f=4):
    return a + c
```

In the above example we don't care about `d=`, `e=` and `f=` args when looking up a cache value, so we can squash them all out with **kwargs.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this answer with what key and hashkey are?

Comment: For anyone else wanting an answer to [@Tommy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730983/make-lru-cache-ignore-some-of-the-function-arguments/32655449#comment123792060_32655449), I was able to find the description of `key` and `hashkey` in [this section of the `cachetools` docs](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#cachetools.cached). Essentially, `key` is a function which returns a cache key, and `hashkey()` returns a tuple of its args as an internal cache key and verifies that each arg is hashable.

Comment: What does this print? Does it print:

`processing 0\n
result: 0\n
processing 1\n
result: 1\n
processing 2\n
result: 2\n
processing 3\n
result: 3\n
processing 4\n
result: 4\n
result: 0\n
result: 1\n
result: 2\n
result: 3\n
result: 4\n
`

???

Comment: @Tommy, I edited the answer to include more explanation around the syntax needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: in general for function `def function(a,b):` where only b is to be used as a cache key, do `@cached(cache={}, key=lambda a,b: hashkey(b))`   (syntax is confusing on the first look)

Comment: I cannot edit my comment, so 1. yes you must use all the stuff, lambdas etc (I was hoping for smt simple like `@cached(key='b'`) and 2. the `cache={}` what feels like oddly forcing me to declare  default empty parameters is actually "The cache argument specifies a cache object to store previous function arguments and return values" i.e. using dictionary as a cache object

Answer (score 14):

I have at least one very ugly solution. Wrap `db_handle` in a object that's always equals, and unwrap it inside the function.

It requires a decorator with quite a bit of helper functions, which makes stack trace quite confusing.

```
class _Equals(object):
    def __init__(self, o):
        self.obj = o

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

def lru_cache_ignoring_first_argument(*args, **kwargs):
    lru_decorator = functools.lru_cache(*args, **kwargs)

    def decorator(f):
        @lru_decorator
        def helper(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
            arg1 = arg1.obj
            return f(arg1, *args, **kwargs)

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def function(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
            arg1 = _Equals(arg1)
            return helper(arg1, *args, **kwargs)

        return function

    return decorator
```

Comment: I am reviving this very old answer, but how would you use the `lru_cache_ignoring_first_argument` decorator?

Comment: @Sanandrea, you just put `@lru_cache_ignoring_first_argument()`directly above your function.